# Thanking and Addressing multiple people including the reader in an email

Tags: business-language

Let's say I am writing a business email, starting by thanking a bunch of people who helped me in the past project.

Those people include:

Aaron: Person of importance who helped me (in a high position, such as director or president)

Bob: Aaron's subordinate who helped me (not in a high position)

Chris: Contact person who helped me and will be reading the email ("you" in the email)

David: Minor support compared to Aaron, Bob and Chris, but still worth mentioning

The thing is that I am thanking people that is not directly related to the topic of this current email, which is why it will be sent to Chris instead of Aaron. It is basically "Thank you all for helping us last time", but addressing every person who helped.

So, if I go by "thanks to", I assume it would be like this:

> Thanks to Aaron, Bob, you and David, we were able to ...

In this case, I wonder "you" in the middle of the list would like a bit unnatural, and I also wonder if David after "you" might stand out and imply that I am downplaying David's help.

It would be great if I can know how to address and thank those 4 people naturally and politely in an email.

Comment: I suppose the other people will get cc'ed.  I've noticed that most people don't make much of a distinction between "to" and "cc."  So I think your choices are "Thanks to Aaron, Bob, Chris and David, we were able to etc." or "Thanks again to all for etc."

Comment: Send each a letter individually and thank watch singly:  Dear Chris, I want to thank you for your help…   Dear Bob, I want to thank you for your help…   Etc.

Comment: What @Jim said. That would definitely be my approach, and it's far less likely to leave any of the recipients disappointed or affronted. It also gives you the opportunity to tailor each email to the individual and their specific contribution.